# what join use to both two tables

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join, where-clause

I have one table with all users of my system with the columns userid and user_name.

Each user have a calendar, and can shared this with other users.

This table hable two columns, userid is the field of the user that shared the calendar, and sharedid is the user with whom the calendar is shared.

I want to create a query to know if a certain user does not share their calendar.

I can't understand how to join both tables to find out.

For example, the userid=13393 not share your calendar and this query return 0 results:

```
SELECT * FROM vtiger_sharedcalendar WHERE userid=13393
```

If I wanted to know with which users the userid=13393 does NOT share the calendar, how should join the tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 0):

> If I wanted to know with which users the userid=13393 does NOT share the calendar, how should join the tables?

You could use `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from vtiger_sharedcalendar c
    where c.userid = 13393 and c.sharedid = u.userid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the users that don't have a shared calendar and they are not in the other table I think the Join you are looking for is a left join, the values that don't exist in the other table should be null.